# Win32 Handle WM_NOTIFY message from Rich Edit Control

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How can I retrieve information about what change is being made in a rich edit control when handling `WM_NOTIFY`? More specifically, I am confused because in the [documentation for WM_NOTIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify) it says that `lParam` points to an `NMHDR` structure but in [the page for EN_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change--rich-edit-control-) they say that `lParam` points to a `CHANGENOTIFY` structure. What does `lParam` point to exactly?

Comment: I think it's a documentation bug; EN_CHANGE is sent via WM_COMMAND and doesn't include a pointer to a data structure.

Comment: It is not a documentation bug (well, not the way you are thinking). There are two separate `EN_CHANGE` messages, one for *windowed* RichEdit controls, and one for *windowless* RichEdit controls. The OP is referring to the latter, but will likely be receiving the former.  The real documentation bug is that some of the pages in the RichEdit docs are linking to the wrong `EN_CHANGE` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the `EN_CHANGE` documentation you linked to more carefully, you will notice this caveat:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change--rich-edit-control-

> Notifies a **windowless** rich edit control's host window that a change has occurred. A rich edit control sends this notification code in the form of a `WM_NOTIFY` message.

See [Windowless Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/windowless-rich-edit-controls) for more details.  And, as you noted, this message's `CHANGENOTIFY` struct does not conform to the standard use of `WM_NOTIFY`.  The message carries only the RichEdit's control ID in the `wParam`, there is no `NMHDR*` in the `lParam`.

If you are using a **windowed** Rich Edit control instead (which I assume you are), then it uses the same `EN_CHANGE` message that standard Edit controls use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change

> Sent when the user has taken an action that may have altered text in an edit control. Unlike the `EN_UPDATE` notification code, this notification code is sent after the system updates the screen. **The parent window of the edit control receives this notification code through a `WM_COMMAND` message.**
>
> ...
>
> Rich Edit: Supported in Microsoft Rich Edit 1.0 and later. To receive `EN_CHANGE` notification codes, specify `ENM_CHANGE` in the mask sent with the `EM_SETEVENTMASK` message. For information about the compatibility of rich edit versions with the various system versions, see [About Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls).